# How can I use my python program on my desktop (windows 7) to display a simple notification on my desktop without notify2, notify-send, pqt5?

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I tried those 3 options and they don't work.

Notifiy-send is not a command and I don't have linux or ubuntu.

I can't import notify2 in python, because I get the error where it says that the notify2 library can't import dbus, and I tried to pip3 install dbus, but it doesn't exist (what???). I can't install homebrew to fix it.

pqt5 runs without compile errors, but no notification is showing up. It works fine in my mac, but not on my windows pc.

Comment: Do you want a tray-icon notification or a simple alert-like window?

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. A simple alert-like window is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#how-tk-and-tkinter-are-related), which is an interface for the Tk GUI toolkit.

On Python 3:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw() # This hides the main window of the gui
messagebox.showinfo("Pay attention", "Something happened!")
```

On Python 2:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw() # This hides the main window of the gui
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Pay attention", "Something happened!")
```

This creates a simple popup alert and should work on Windows.